# Animate background color to different colors

Tags: css, animation, colors

How can I animate the back ground color of a `div` from the lightest orange color to the darkest red color, and back (which should make it look like a glow effect)?

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddFG3/) but it only changes colors from light grey (static set) to red. This is as far as I got.

I did found a few questions regarding animating colors, but nothing about multiple colors.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this CSS to your div.
http://jsfiddle.net/Nillervision/a4ELz/

```
.test {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 3;    
    -webkit-animation: glow linear 1s infinite; 
    animation: glow linear 1s infinite;
} 
@-webkit-keyframes glow { 
    0% { background-color:red; }
    50% { background-color:orange; }
    100% { background-color:red; } 

} 
@keyframes glow { 
    0% { background-color:red; }
    50% { background-color:orange; }
    100% { background-color:red; } 
}
```

If you only want the animation to run once on pageload remove the "infinite" value.
If you want the effect to happen on hover you could use css transitions instead.

Comment: Hi, looks great, but I want it from orange to red. Can i Just change the order of these colors? And if i want some more shades, do i have to add a few more lines like `50% { background-color:orange; }` with different percentage?

Comment: Yes to both questions. You can add as many keyframes as you want and you can animate any color (or any other CSS property for that matter)